# Python: accessing list elements

Tags: python, list

So I have this list

```
X = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]
```

How can I access all the last elements like `Y = [3,3,3]`?

`Y=X[0:2][2]` doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 9):

I think a list comprehension would be the easiest way to do this. https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

```
Y = [i[-1] for i in X]
```

The -1 will get the last element of the lists. but this can be changed to get any element from these lists.

Comment: I up voted your answer, but your code will break if the sub-list in the OP's list are greater than three elements. Instead of using "hard-coding" to get the last element, use `i[-1]` to _always_ get the last element.

Answer (score 4):

Use [-1] to acces last item in list.

```
x_last = [i[-1] for i in X]
```

Answer (score 0):

`zip` is an alternative:

```
>>> X = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]
>>> list(list(zip(*X))[-1])
[3, 3, 3]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Y = [m[-1] for m in X]
```

The index `-1` means the last element of a list.

Comment: Triple ticks don't work on SO unfortunately. You have to indent everything by four spaces to get the same effect.

Comment: @MadPhysicist What are you saying about?